# Dynamic way to iterate using pagination, Python, Pandas and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Thanks to contributors his code is efficient and runs well.  There are two shortcomings, namely: 1) The **Tail_Number** field
Isn’t captured accurately.  For example the first page **manuf/Boeing_Vertol.html** **Tail_Number** record should read 01001.  On the third page **/manuf/Boeing_Vertol:3.html** these *Tail_Number** records “5-4006” , ”5-4054” , ”5-4083” should not be captured as date-like “May-4006” , ”May-4054” , ”May-4083” .   2) I would like to, if possible, to iterate through https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/09.html to https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Z.html and dump each **Aircraft by Manufacturer** in its own **.csv** file

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import Request

headers =   {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        }

url = 'https://www.airport-data.com/manuf/Boeing_Vertol.html'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = []

while True:
    print(url)
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(html.text, 'html.parser')
    data.append(pd.read_html(soup.select_one('table').prettify())[0])

    if soup.select_one('li.active + li a[href]'):
        url = soup.select_one('li.active + li a')['href']
    else:
        break
df = pd.concat(data)
df.to_csv("Boeing_Vertol.csv",encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)
```

Comment: If the code works and you need a review, you should try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because your question is off-topic here. See [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No, code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's functionally complete.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *There should be only one question at a time - answer is focused on your first one.

To avoid converting values to date you can set `parse_dates=False` for `pandas.read_html()`:

```
data.append(pd.read_html(soup.select_one('table').prettify(), parse_dates=False)[0])
```

Comment: I tried the code with the above proposed amendment. The output **.csv** file yields these erroneous Tail_Number “ 1001“ instead of “ 01001“ and Tail_Number " May-4006 " instead of “ 05-4006 “

Comment: Not sure in what way there should be dependencies in the versions of the libraries or in terms of the system - running the code even without customisations via jupyter on windows , work fine, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the original solutions. What does your setup look like?

Comment: I'm running Sublime Text version 3.2.2 - Pandas 1.3.4 - BeautifulSoup4  4.10.0 - Python 3.8.12 on  macOS Monterey.   OK so this is interesting, I tried Jupiter and agree with you that it works.  When the file is downloaded the results contained in the csv.file is changed and contains the error mentioned earlier, as posted.  Somehow the Jupiter download creates the problems.